# Using single Apple ID with multiple Apple Developer Program memberships

Tags: developer-program

My company has an Enterprise account to which I am enrolled under Developer role. The invitation was sent to my personal Apple ID.

Now, I want to enroll into Apple Developer program as an individual, just for my apps (have nothing to do with my company) using the same Apple ID.

Is it that possible or do I have to leave the team to create it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single Apple ID can be a part of more than one, different development teams.

You are enrolled in the Enterprise account as a Developer. You can easily use your Apple ID to enroll into [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) as an individual.

Once your membership request is approved, you'll be the Agent in your personal team and Developer in the company's Enterprise team. When using your Apple ID to log into [Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com) or into Xcode, you'll be given the option to select the team of your choosing.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of different development teams a single Apple ID can be a part of?

Comment: @Nemesh Neema when I click through it, I will be not asked for a credit-card detail etc. I only can purchase in the end. Will it be purchased via the existing organization?